# PreparedStatement multiple replacements without a comma separator

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I have the following PreparedStatement:

```
  PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from foo 
          where foo.age ? ? AND foo.children ? ?")
```

Now to explain what I am looking to do, because I am lazy and don't like writing multiple queries.  I want the statement to look like the following when finished:

```
Select * from foo where foo.age >= 42 AND foo.children <= 3
```

OR

```
Select * from foo where foo.age = 42 AND foo.children = 3
```

If it isn't clear I want to be able to substitute multiple tokens in a row, where the first token happens to be a qualifier (equals,greater,less,etc) and the token following it happens to be a literal (3,17,"Steve",etc).  My question is is this possible and if so how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why does nobody mention to create a suitable `PreparedStatement` right before it's needed and discard it right afterwards? Is this not a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this, because `?` doesn't represent a *token*, but rather a *value*. Obviously some tokens (namely literals) represent values, but even for these, the `?` directly represents the value itself, not the literal-that-also-represents-the-value. (This is an intentional element of the design, because the very purpose of parameterized queries is to prevent parameters from "leaking out" and being interpreted as something other than single values.)

---

**Edited to add:** Where I work, we have a custom framework that wraps around JDBC and handles transactions and so on, so we don't *usually* have to deal with `PreparedStatement` directly. That framework has a method that looks something like this:

```
public <T> Iterator<T> executeQuery(ConverterFromResultSetToT<T> converter,
                                     String query, Map<String, Object> params)
{
    // . . . modify query, replacing any instances of $!{paramKey} with the
    //       corresponding value from params -- this allows arbitrary SQL code
    //       to be injected, in the rare cases that that's necessary

    // . . . modify query, replacing any instances of ${paramKey} with '?' and
    //       adding the corresponding value from params to an array -- we use
    //       this much more often

    // . . . create PreparedStatement with the resulting query

    // . . . set parameters of PreparedStatement from aforemented array

    // . . . run PreparedStatement; wrap result in an Iterator<T>; and return
}
```

But I'd only recommend that sort of thing if you expect to be doing a lot of this. We put a lot of effort into that framework, and it's incredibly useful, but it's also a lot of code.

---

It's worth noting that, despite what the documentation might imply, the cost of creating a `PreparedStatement` is not very high. Unless you're really running the same query a large number of times, it's not a big deal if you re-create the `PreparedStatement` each time. So you don't really need built-in support for drop-in operators, as long as you're willing to write your own code for that.

Comment: Sure.  So can this be done with a regular `Statement` object?

Comment: @Woot4Moo you can do it creating the sql string dinamically by concatenating the correct operator. But it has nothing to do with it being a `Statement` or a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: We have a white list capability that has abstracted us from knowing the database implementation underneath, which is where this issue arose.  But good to know.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. The parameters in a `PreparedSatement` can only be values, not operators, table names and such like.

Now, for the specific queries above you can do the following:

```
select * from foo where age > ? and age < ?
```

Then with `42`, `400` you get `age>=42` years and with `42`, `42` you get `age = 42`

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to do this to allow multiple replacements with the parent Statement object?

Comment: Don't know what you mean, `Statement` doesn't allow any parameter at all, unless it is a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 2):

You can have a workaround as :

```
String query = "Select * from foo where foo.age @ @ AND foo.children @ @";

//write code here to manipulate your query string using
query = query.replaceFirst("@", "=");
query = query.replaceFirst("@", "42");
query = query.replaceFirst("@", "=");
query = query.replaceFirst("@", "3");

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query );
```

**If you decide to use `replaceFirst` as above, please be aware that you are assigning the value `from left to right`**.

Answer (score 0):

```
String firstOperator = ">="
String secondOperator = "<="

PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from foo 
          where foo.age "+firstOperator+" ? AND foo.children "+secondOperator+" ?");

statement.setInt(1,42);
statement.setInt(2,3);
```

Anyway I don't think it's a very elegant thing to do. "Not writing multiple queries" doesn't seem to be a sensible design goal.